# Invert Rc wrapped boolean

Tags: rust

What's the proper way to invert an `bool` wrapped in an `Rc<RefCell<>>`?

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn main(){
    let my_wrapped_bool = Rc::from(RefCell::from(true));
    *my_wrapped_bool.borrow_mut() ^= *my_wrapped_bool.borrow();
}
```

Obviously we can't borrow mut and borrow at the same time, but seems like we need some kind of reference to the inner value in order to invert.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'already borrowed: BorrowMutError', src/main.rs:5:22
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/)

Comment: `RefCell<bool>` is a bit "overkill"... `Cell<bool>` would be sufficient. `let my_wrapped_bool = Rc::from(Cell::from(true)); my_wrapped_bool.set(!my_wrapped_bool.get());` Also, XORing the boolean with itself will not invert it; it will always set it to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call the borrow method twice, but you can re-use the `&mut bool` returned by `borrow_mut()`

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

fn main(){
    let my_wrapped_bool = Rc::from(RefCell::from(true));
    
    let mut borrowed_bool = my_wrapped_bool.borrow_mut();
    *borrowed_bool = !*borrowed_bool;
}
```

Edit: As other have pointed out, xoring it with itself will always set it to false.

Comment: Also, as noted in the comment, this will just set the bool to false, not invert it. To invert it you'd need `*borrowed_bool = !*borrowed_bool`.

Comment: @user4815162342: Or if you want to be fancy: `*borrowed_bool ^= true;` because `bool` implements `BitXorAssign`.

Comment: @rodrigo It's nice to notice that LLVM generates [identical code for both](https://godbolt.org/z/s8GseTz6K), as if `^= true` were written.

Comment: Won't `*borrowed_bool ^= *borrowed_bool` always set `*borrowed_bool` to `false`?